# where can I find youtube XML Schema

Tags: php, xml, youtube

Where can I find the xml schema for youtube xml below ?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' 
xmlns:openSearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/' 
xmlns:gml='http://www.opengis.net/gml' xmlns:georss='http://www.georss.org/georss' 
xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/' 
xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007' 
xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'>
  <id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_viewed</id>
  <updated>2008-03-06T14:43:27.000-08:00</updated>
  <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' 
  term='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video'/>
  <title type='text'>Most Viewed</title>
  <logo>http://www.youtube.com/img/pic_youtubelogo_123x63.gif</logo>
  <link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='http://www.youtube.com/browse?s=mp'/>
  <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed' type='application/atom+xml' 
  href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_viewed'/>
  <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' 
  href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_viewed
  ?start-index=1&max-results=5'/>
  <link rel='next' type='application/atom+xml' 
  href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_viewed
  ?start-index=6&max-results=5'/>
  <author>
    <name>YouTube</name>
    <uri>http://www.youtube.com/</uri>
  </author>
  <generator version='beta' uri='http://gdata.youtube.com/'>
  YouTube data API</generator>
  <openSearch:totalResults>94</openSearch:totalResults>
  <openSearch:startIndex>1</openSearch:startIndex>
  <openSearch:itemsPerPage>5</openSearch:itemsPerPage>
  <entry>
    <id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/dMH0bHeiRNg</id>
    <published>2006-04-06T14:30:53.000-07:00</published>
    <updated>2008-03-12T00:22:25.000-07:00</updated>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' 
    term='Dancing'/>
    <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' 
    term='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/keywords.cat' 
    term='comedy'/>
    <category scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat' 
    term='Comedy' label='Comedy'/>
    <title type='text'>Evolution of Dance</title>
    <content type='text'>The funniest 6 minutes you will ever see! 
    Remember how many of these you have done!
Judson Laipply is dancing -
http://www.evolutionofdance.com -
for more info including song list!</content>
    <link rel='alternate' type='text/html' 
    href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dMH0bHeiRNg'/>
    <link rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video.responses' 
    type='application/atom+xml' 
    href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/dMH0bHeiRNg/responses'/>
    <link rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#video.related' 
    type='application/atom+xml' 
    href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/dMH0bHeiRNg/related'/>
    <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' 
    href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_viewed/dMH0bHeiRNg'/>
    <author>
      <name>judsonlaipply</name>
      <uri>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/judsonlaipply</uri>
    </author>
    <media:group>
      <media:title type='plain'>Evolution of Dance</media:title>
      <media:description type='plain'>The funniest 6 minutes you will ever see!
       Remember how many of these you have done!
Judson Laipply is dancing -
http://www.evolutionofdance.com -
for more info including song list!</media:description>
      <media:keywords>comedy, Dancing</media:keywords>
      <yt:duration seconds='360'/>
      <media:category label='Comedy' 
      scheme='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat'>Comedy
      </media:category>
      <media:content 
      url='http://www.youtube.com/v/dMH0bHeiRNg' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' 
      medium='video' isDefault='true' expression='full' duration='360' yt:format='5'/>
      <media:content 
      url='rtsp://rtsp2.youtube.com/ChoLENy73wIaEQnYRKJ3bPTBdBMYDSANFEgGDA==
      /0/0/0/video.3gp' type='video/3gpp' medium='video' expression='full' duration='360'
       yt:format='1'/>
      <media:content 
      url='rtsp://rtsp2.youtube.com/ChoLENy73wIaEQnYRKJ3bPTBdBMYESARFEgGDA==
      /0/0/0/video.3gp' type='video/3gpp' medium='video' expression='full' duration='360'
       yt:format='6'/>
      <media:player url='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dMH0bHeiRNg'/>
      <media:thumbnail 
      url='http://img.youtube.com/vi/dMH0bHeiRNg/2.jpg' height='97' width='130' 
      time='00:03:00'/>
      <media:thumbnail 
      url='http://img.youtube.com/vi/dMH0bHeiRNg/1.jpg' height='97' width='130' 
      time='00:01:30'/>
      <media:thumbnail 
      url='http://img.youtube.com/vi/dMH0bHeiRNg/3.jpg' height='97' width='130' 
      time='00:04:30'/>
      <media:thumbnail 
      url='http://img.youtube.com/vi/dMH0bHeiRNg/0.jpg' height='240' width='320' 
      time='00:03:00'/>
    </media:group>
    <yt:statistics viewCount='78060679' favoriteCount='400468'/>
    <gd:rating min='1' max='5' numRaters='276123' average='4.65'/>
    <gd:comments>
      <gd:feedLink href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/dMH0bHeiRNg
      /comments' countHint='124130'/>
    </gd:comments>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/cQ25-glGRzI</id>
    <published>2007-02-27T15:08:01.000-08:00</published>
    <updated>2008-03-12T00:46:25.000-07:00</updated>
    ...
  </entry>
</feed>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/youtube-api-gdata/browse_thread/thread/d0aaa6457d76dc61) there is no schema for the Youtube API

Comment: It's a sad thing to see people accept a solution based on two year old knowledge. Especially when in the two old knowledge, there is mention of it coming out eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere around here, i'd say: http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html